# WPF command in code behind not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I'm working on a **WPF** application using the **MVVM** pattern and I'm still fairly new to .NET development. My understanding is that the **View** should set its data context to a **ViewModel** and then any data related processing should be done in the **ViewModel** while the **UI** part should be handled in the view (**XAML** or **code behind**).

So I have a menu with each menu item bound to a **DelegateCommand** (using **Prism**) declared and handled in the **ViewModel** with keyboard shortcuts and it works flawlessly. However, I wanted to **bind** a menu item to a **command** in the **View's code behind** file as it doesn't manupulate any data (it just shows or hide a panel).

**View (XAML)**

```
<Window x:Class="Editor.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Editor.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="RootWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Width="1200" Height="650">

    <!-- Data Context -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <!-- Keyboard Shortcuts -->
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="L" Command="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ToggleLayersCommand}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="View" Padding="5, 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Toggle Layers Panel" InputGestureText="CTRL + L" Command="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ToggleLayersCommand}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Window>
```

**View (Code behind)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DelegateCommand ToggleLayersCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToggleLayersCommand = new DelegateCommand(ToggleLayersCommand_OnExecuted, () => true);
    }

    private void ToggleLayersCommand_OnExecuted()
    {
        LayerListPanel.Visibility = (LayerListPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

I named the window in XAML to find the **command** in the **View** instead of the **ViewModel** when binding the **Command attribute**. It seems to find it since I'm getting **intellisense** but it never fires.

I could use a **click event** instead even though I'd rather use a **command** but then how to **bind** the **keyboard shortcut** to the **event**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define the command inside the ViewModel and have it change a property `public Visibility LayerListPanelVisibility` (which should also be defined in the ViewModel). Then I would bind `LayerListPanel.Visibility` to this property.

Keep your code-behind as empty as possible.

---

The reason that the command is not found by your Binding is that `ToggleLayersCommand` is `null` when the Binding is resolved. It is only shortly after binding resolution that you assign the proper command to `ToggleLayersCommand`. However, the Binding will not be updated as your Viewmodel does not raise a `PropertyChanged` event.

If you want to keep your command in the View, you can either raise a `PropertyChanged` event when you have assigned the command or you assign the command before you call `InitializeComponent`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ToggleLayersCommand = new DelegateCommand(ToggleLayersCommand_OnExecuted, () => true);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: So even if it has nothing to do with data it's fine to put it in the ViewModel?

Comment: It is logic controlling the view. That's exactly what the ViewModel is supposed to be.

Comment: Well i think i have a better understanding now and yes binding the command before InitializeComponent works but i think I'm going to move it to the ViewModel instead.

Comment: Having a dependency to WPF specific `Visiblity` enum in your ViewModel is pointless and you might as well put that in code-behind. The point of having a view model is to connect the business logic to the GUI with as little dependencies as possible, to maximize usability and testability. If you actually wanted to make it MVVM, you would make the propperty something that relates to the business logic like `UserHasPermission` and use a converter to convert it to something the view understands. Using a view model just 'cause is bad advice. The view model should know nothing about the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `ViewModel` for command and not the `View`:

ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand ToggleLayersCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ToggleLayersCommand = new DelegateCommand(ToggleLayersCommand_OnExecuted, () => true);
    }

    private void ToggleLayersCommand_OnExecuted()
    {
        LayerListPanel.Visibility = (LayerListPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; 
//THIS WILL PROBABLY NOT WORK...
//You can use another public property to change your visibility.
// Create a public visibility and bind it to the correct item
    }
 }
```

XAML:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="View" Padding="5, 2">
       <MenuItem Header="Toggle Layers Panel" InputGestureText="CTRL + L" Command="{Binding Path=ToggleLayersCommand}" />
        </MenuItem>
 </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with binding command to keybinding. All I have done is give to a button its own name and from view code behind set command to yours.

My example looks like so:

```
<KeyBinding x:Name="ShowDetailsKeyBinding"
                Key="D"
                Modifiers="Control" />
```

Code behind:

```
ShowDetailsKeyBinding.Command = new DelegateCommand(ShowDetailsOperation);
```

I use this solution to run my animations, other way you should create command in yours ViewModel.